# "TypeError: (Integer) is not JSON serializable" when serializing JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, encoding, typeerror

I am trying to send a simple dictionary to a json file from python, but I keep getting the "TypeError: 1425 is not JSON serializable" message.

```
import json
alerts = {'upper':[1425],'lower':[576],'level':[2],'datetime':['2012-08-08 15:30']}
afile = open('test.json','w')
afile.write(json.dumps(alerts,encoding='UTF-8'))
afile.close()
```

If I add the default argument, then it writes, but the integer values are written to the json file as strings, which is undesirable.

```
afile.write(json.dumps(alerts,encoding='UTF-8',default=str))
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to "duplicate" that question ..

Comment: I found my problem.  The issue was that my integers were actually type numpy.int64.

Comment: @user1329894 Post as a solution/explanation and self-close ..

Comment: -0 for writing a minimal repro that doesn't actually reproduce the bug.

Comment: The underlying problem is the same: data that looks like an "ordinary" type, but is a different type that doesn't support serialization. In this case it was a Numpy numeric type instead of `int`; in the other case, a custom mapping instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 309):

I found my problem. The issue was that my integers were actually type [`numpy.int64`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.types.html).

Comment: I had to deal with this issue too, and your answer pointed me in the right direction. I just wanted to add [a link to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types) that can help in actually solving the problem.

Comment: That'd be nice if the JSON unserializable error message could display the type of the object...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27050186/310441) is a tidy solution that uses a custom serializer.

Comment: It works perfectly on ubuntu but not on windows. Please help.

Comment: Great catch.  Happens with AWS Lambda (Python 3.6) serialization as well. (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=689708)

Comment: That's the problem, but what's the solution?

Comment: x.astype(int) or int(x)

Comment: x.astype(int) or int(x) not working in python3.5.
this is what i am doing.

data['id'] = data['id'].astype(int)

Comment: the serializer solution worked for me in my flask project

Comment: For me, just int(x) is working, not astype(x). Strange.

Answer (score 71):

It seems like there may be a issue to dump numpy.int64 into json string in Python 3 and the python team already have a conversation about it. More details can be found [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue24313).

There is a workaround provided by Serhiy Storchaka. It works very well so I paste it here:

```
def convert(o):
    if isinstance(o, numpy.int64): return int(o)  
    raise TypeError

json.dumps({'value': numpy.int64(42)}, default=convert)
```

Comment: A wonderful workaround provided by Serhiy. Please check his approach. And to add, just: json.dumps(yourObject, default=default); like here.

Answer (score 13):

as @JAC pointed out in the comments of the highest rated answer, the generic solution (for all numpy types) can be found in the thread  [Converting numpy dtypes to native python types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types).

Nevertheless, I´ll add my version of the solution below, as my in my case I needed a generic solution that combines these answers and with the answers of the other thread. This should work with almost all numpy types.

```
def convert(o):
    if isinstance(o, np.generic): return o.item()  
    raise TypeError

json.dumps({'value': numpy.int64(42)}, default=convert)
```

Comment: Nice answer indeed

Answer (score 10):

## Just convert numbers from `int64` (from numpy) to `int`.

For example, if variable `x` is a int64:

```
int(x)
```

If is array of int64:

```
map(int, x)
```

Answer (score 8):

You have **Numpy Data Type**, Just change to normal `int()` or `float()` data type. it will work fine.

Answer (score 6):

This might be the late response, but recently i got the same error. After lot of surfing this solution helped me.

```
alerts = {'upper':[1425],'lower':[576],'level':[2],'datetime':['2012-08-08 15:30']}
def myconverter(obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.__str__()
```

Call `myconverter` in `json.dumps()` like below. `json.dumps(alerts, default=myconverter).`

Answer (score 4):

This solved the problem for me:

```
def serialize(self):
    return {
        my_int: int(self.my_int), 
        my_float: float(self.my_float)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Same problem. List contained numbers of **`type numpy.int64 which throws a TypeError`**. Quick workaround for me was to

```
mylist = eval(str(mylist_of_integers))
json.dumps({'mylist': mylist})
```

which converts `list` to `str()` and `eval()` function evaluates the **String** like a **Python** expression and returns the result as a `list of integers` in my case.

Comment: Just noticed eval(str()) is very slow so use with caution. @shiva's answer is much better: json.dumps(alerts, default=myconverter)

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code to resolve the issue.

```
import json
from numpyencoder import NumpyEncoder
alerts = {'upper':[1425],'lower':[576],'level':[2],'datetime':['2012-08-08 
15:30']}
afile = open('test.json','w')
afile.write(json.dumps(alerts,encoding='UTF-8',cls=NumpyEncoder))
afile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can convert your object into a dataframe first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(obj)
```

and then save this `dataframe` in a `json` file:

```
df.to_json(path_or_buf='df.json')
```

Hope this helps