# Convert numpy type to python

Tags: python, json, numpy, pandas

I have a list of dicts in the following form that I generate from pandas. I want to convert it to a json format.

```
list_val = [{1.0: 685}, {2.0: 8}]
output = json.dumps(list_val)
```

However, json.dumps throws an error: TypeError: 685 is not JSON serializable

I am guessing it's a type conversion issue from numpy to python(?).

However, when I convert the values v of each dict in the array using np.int32(v) it still throws the error.

EDIT: Here's the full code

```
            new = df[df[label] == label_new] 
            ks_dict = json.loads(content)
            ks_list = ks_dict['variables']
            freq_counts = []

            for ks_var in ks_list:

                    freq_var = dict()
                    freq_var["name"] = ks_var["name"]
                    ks_series = new[ks_var["name"]]
                    temp_df = ks_series.value_counts().to_dict()
                    freq_var["new"] = [{u: np.int32(v)} for (u, v) in temp_df.iteritems()]            
                    freq_counts.append(freq_var)

           out = json.dumps(freq_counts)
```

Comment: your code works fine for me... (Python 3.4.2) - `[{"1.0": 685}, {"2.0": 8}]`

Comment: so `list_val`  is a numpy array?

Comment: Yes, it's generated from a DataFrame. I'll update the full code in the post

Comment: So… is there a reason you're putting `np.int32(v)` instead of `v` (or `int(v)`; not sure what `v` is) in `freq_var`?

Comment: Also, when you have problems like this in the future, try looking at first the `repr` and then the `type` of each object, not just printing out their `str`. (And include the results in your question.) It's a lot easier to just know you have an `np.float32` or whatever than to have to guess that maybe there's some kind of type conversion issue.

Comment: I used int32 assuming that would resolve the Type Error. However, when I changed np.int32(v) to np.int(v),it worked.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It looks like you're correct:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(numpy.int32(685))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: 685 is not JSON serializable
```

The unfortunate thing here is that numpy numbers' `__repr__` doesn't give you any hint about what *type* they are.  They're running around masquerading as `int`s when they aren't (*gasp*).  Ultimately, it looks like `json` is telling you that an `int` isn't serializable, but really, it's telling you that this particular np.int32 (or whatever type you actually have) isn't serializable.  (No real surprise there -- No np.int32 *is* serializable).  This is also why the dict that you inevitably printed *before* passing it to `json.dumps` looks like it just has integers in it as well.

The easiest workaround here is probably to [write your own serializer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)<sup>1</sup>:

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, numpy.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, numpy.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, numpy.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        else:
            return super(MyEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

You use it like this:

```
json.dumps(numpy.float32(1.2), cls=MyEncoder)
json.dumps(numpy.arange(12), cls=MyEncoder)
json.dumps({'a': numpy.int32(42)}, cls=MyEncoder)
```

etc.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Or you could just write the default function and pass that as the `defaut` keyword argument to `json.dumps`.  In this scenario, you'd replace the last line with `raise TypeError`, but ... meh.  The class is more extensible :-)</sup>

Comment: For real fun, try this with `np.float64` or `np.bool` and everything works fine, because they're actually subclasses of `float` and `bool`. Once you think about it, it makes sense why those two types are subclasses but none of the other numeric types are, but until you do, it can make for some real fun debugging…

Comment: @abarnert -- `np.float64` _is_ obvious (after all, it's just C's `double` which is what python uses for `float`), but `np.bool` isn't so much.  It could have been a subclass of `np.int32` I would think...  Looking at the `__mro__` of `np.int64`, I would expect that one to work too -- at least on python2.x :-).

Comment: Or you could convert the numpy type to a native type. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389998/2486302 for details on how to do this.

Comment: Or you can use the `json_tricks` library which does this by default (disclaimer: I'm the main contributor).

Comment: unfortunately the json spec does not support complex values... so i think any code that converts complex values to json will be kind of hacky. or at least my attempt smelled hacky.

Comment: Seems like `eval(repr(numpy_var))` works more generally (tested with int32/float32) but not very pleasant

Answer (score 4):

You could also convert the array to a python list (use the `tolist` method) and then convert the list to json.

Answer (score 2):

You can use our fork of ujson to deal with NumPy int64. [caiyunapp/ultrajson: Ultra fast JSON decoder and encoder written in C with Python bindings and NumPy bindings](https://github.com/caiyunapp/ultrajson)

```sh
pip install nujson
```

Then

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import nujson as ujson
>>> a = {"a": np.int64(100)}
>>> ujson.dumps(a)
'{"a":100}'
>>> a["b"] = np.float64(10.9)
>>> ujson.dumps(a)
'{"a":100,"b":10.9}'
>>> a["c"] = np.str_("12")
>>> ujson.dumps(a)
'{"a":100,"b":10.9,"c":"12"}'
>>> a["d"] = np.array(list(range(10)))
>>> ujson.dumps(a)
'{"a":100,"b":10.9,"c":"12","d":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}'
>>> a["e"] = np.repeat(3.9, 4)
>>> ujson.dumps(a)
'{"a":100,"b":10.9,"c":"12","d":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"e":[3.9,3.9,3.9,3.9]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

In a simpler case when you only have numpy numbers to be converted the easiest is:

```
json.dumps(a, default=float)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the data in any of the `pandas` objects, the library supplies a `to_json` function on Series, DataFrame, and all of the other higher dimension cousins.

See [Series.to_json()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html?highlight=json#pandas.Series.to_json)

Comment: This wouldn't work as Series.to_json() still can't handle numpy.ndarrays

Comment: After a lot of head-banging and resistance to create a custom function or class for a seemingly straightforward problem, this worked for me!! I like it because it keeps things simple!

Answer (score 1):

In some cases simple `json.dump(eval(str(a)), your_file)` helps.

Comment: That's a horrible hack, but it's considerably more concise for a complex data structure I encountered with some float32 instances hidden around.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dict consists of multiple numpy objects like ndarray or a float32 object you can manually convert an ndarray to a list using `.tolist()`

```py
import numpy as np
import json

a = np.empty([2, 2], dtype=np.float32)
json.dumps(a.tolist()) # this should work
```

or save a float32 object using `.item()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import json

a = np.float32(1)
json.dumps(a.item()) # this should work
```

But if you have a complex dict with multiple dicts nested in lists which are further nested with numpy objects, navigating your code and manually updating each variable become cumbersome and you might not want to do that. Instead you can define a NumpyEncoder class which handles this for you during the json.dumps() [reference](https://www.programmersought.com/article/84536545794/)

```py
class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.float32):
            return obj.item()
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile: 
    json.dump(json_dict, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4, cls=NumpyEncoder) # indent and sort_keys are just for cleaner output
```

This worked perfectly for me, this even allows us to handle any other data types when saving to JSON example, formatting the decimal places when saving.

```
class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, float):
            return "{:.2f}".format(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```