# Serializing dictionary of lists not working "TypeError: 0.031 is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, json, serialization

For the following code:

```
document_vectors = dict()
for label in d2v_model.docvecs.doctags:
    vector = [ v for v in d2v_model.docvecs[label]]
    document_vectors[label] = list(vector)

document_vectors_file ="../results/amazon_hierarchical_document_vectors.json"

with open(document_vectors_file, "w") as outfile:
    print "Writing document vectors .."
    json.dumps(document_vectors, outfile)
```

I am getting:

```
TypeError: 0.031942371 is not JSON serializable
```

Debugging it shows me that I'm indeed having here a `dict()` of `list()` (I also tried to use just a simple array) but it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly *this* did the trick:

```py
vector = [1.0*v for v in d2v_model.docvecs[label]]
```

The debugger says that `d2v_model.docvecs[label]` returns a `float32`, however, `json` is not happy with it. Multiplying by `1.0` converted it into a `float64` which works all of a sudden.

Might be related to [Convert numpy type to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050108/convert-numpy-type-to-python)