# Rendering scipy.spatial.SphericalVoronoi Output

Tags: python, numpy, three.js, scipy, voronoi

I am attempting to render the output from SciPy SphericalVoronoi using the THREE.js library. I was hoping it would be relatively straight forward based on the matplotlib example in the scipy docs.

**Update 2/18/17:**

I didn't originally account for the voronoi regions being quads, so this splits them into triangles now. I did get the unit cube example working; however, scaling up the geometry doesn't seem to be complete.

Python script:

```
import json
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import SphericalVoronoi

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050108/convert-numpy-type-to-python/27050186#27050186
class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        else:
            return super(NumpyEncoder, self).default(obj)

def computeVoronoi( data ):
    vertices = np.array( data['vertices'] )
    lenVerts = int( vertices.shape[0] / 3 )
    vertices = np.reshape( vertices, ( lenVerts, 3 ) )

    voronoi = SphericalVoronoi( vertices, data['regularRadius'] )

    '''
    points = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, -1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, -1, 0], [-1, 0, 0], ])
    voronoi = SphericalVoronoi( points, 1, np.array([0, 0, 0]) )
    '''

    voronoi.sort_vertices_of_regions()

    return voronoi

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open( './map.json' ) as infile:
        voronoi = computeVoronoi( json.load( infile ) )
        indices = []

        for region in voronoi.regions:
            # need to split the quad into tris for rendering
            i1 = region[0]
            i2 = region[1]
            i3 = region[2]
            i4 = region[3]

            indices.append( i1 )
            indices.append( i2 )
            indices.append( i3 )

            indices.append( i3 )
            indices.append( i4 )
            indices.append( i1 )

        with open( './voronoi.json', 'w' ) as outfile:
            json.dump( {
                'indices': indices,
                'colors': np.random.random( (len( voronoi.vertices ),3) ).flatten(),
                'vertices': voronoi.vertices.flatten()
            }, outfile, cls=NumpyEncoder )
```

THREE.js script:

```
var loader = new THREE.FileLoader()
loader.load( 'voronoi.json', function( data ) {
    vJson = JSON.parse( data )

    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( vJson.vertices ), 3 ) )
    geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( vJson.colors ), 3 ) )
    geometry.setIndex( new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Uint32Array( vJson.indices ), 1 ) )

    var voronoiMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry,
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        })
    )

    scene.add( voronoiMesh )
})
```

Here's what the render looks like now:
[render link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejqou.jpg)

Comment: Discussion continued in part at [https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7046](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7046)