# Pass user built json encoder into Flask's jsonify

Tags: python, json, numpy, flask

I want to pass a numpy JSON serializer I wrote into Flask's `jsonify` function, but I cannot find a way to do this. I cannot use `json.dumps`, because I have to set the status_code of the Flask response when handling an error message. Is there a way to pass the JSON serializer in as a parameter, similar to using the `cls` parameter in `json.dumps` as shown here: [Convert numpy type to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050108/convert-numpy-type-to-python)?
My code is below; thanks.

```
import json
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, jsonify

class JSON_Improved(json.JSONEncoder):
    '''
    Used to help jsonify numpy arrays or lists that contain numpy data types.
    '''
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        else:
            return super(MyEncoder, self).default(obj)

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.errorhandler(ErrorMessage)
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can custom the json encoder of Flask app with `app.json_encoder = JSON_Improved`. `JSON_Improved` inherit from `flask.json.JSONEncoder`

```
class JSON_Improved(JSONEncoder):

    pass
```

There is a Flask Snippets about it in https://web.archive.org/web/20190128005233/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful!

Comment: The link to the snippet is dead because all snippets were removed from the flask website. See [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/website/issues/41) on their website repo. You can get to this snippet at https://web.archive.org/web/20190128005233/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119

Comment: Good answer but out of date! app.json_encoder no longer exists! Check below

Answer (score 18):

Since `json_encoder` got deprecated in Flask 2.2 and would be removed in Flask 2.3, the following update might be useful.

The [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.json.provider.JSONProvider) states that:

> To use a different provider, either subclass `Flask` and set
> `json_provider_class` to a provider class, or set `app.json` to an
> instance of the class.

So, in the case of derived class, the solution would be:

```py
class MyFlask(Flask):
    json_provider_class = CustomJSONProvider

app = MyFlask(__name__)
```

or, in the case of instantiating class `Flask` directly, just:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.json = CustomJSONProvider(app)
```

Given the already defined `JSON_Improved` encoder, sample class `CustomJSONProvider` would be:

```py
from flask.json.provider import JSONProvider
    
    
class CustomJSONProvider(JSONProvider):
    
    def dumps(self, obj, **kwargs):
        return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs, cls=JSON_Improved)
    
    def loads(self, s: str | bytes, **kwargs):
        return json.loads(s, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I used your approach and one deprecation warning disappeared, but the log still says: 'JSONEncoder' is deprecated and will be removed in Flask 2.3. Use 'Flask.json' to provide an alternate JSON implementation instead.
Makes sense since the JSON_Improved class still inherits from JSONEncoder.

Comment: I suggest that `JSONEncoder` should be imported directly from `json` module, not the `flask.json`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For connexion implementation:
...
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from flask.json.provider import JSONProvider
import json
...

...from Dmitry
class CustomJSONProvider(JSONProvider):

    def dumps(self, obj, **kwargs):
        return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs, cls=JSON_Improved)

    def loads(self, s: str | bytes, **kwargs):
        return json.loads(s, **kwargs)

...
    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='.//')
    app.app.json = CustomJSONProvider(app.app)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).