# Why are some numpy datatypes JSON serializable and others not?

Tags: python, json, numpy, serialization, types

Numpy has a lot of different basic types, all of which are [listed here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).

I've tracked down an issue in my program to `float32`s not being JSON-serializable, so I've started testing all datatypes from the list above:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from json import dumps
>>> dumps(np.bool(True))
'true'
>>> dumps(np.bool_(True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 192, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 250, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: True is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.int(0))
'0'
>>> dumps(np.int_(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.intc(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.intp(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.int8(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.int16(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.int32(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.int64(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.uint8(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.uint16(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.uint32(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.uint64(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.float(0))
'0.0'
>>> dumps(np.float_(0))
'0.0'
>>> dumps(np.float16(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0.0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.float32(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0.0 is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.float64(0))
'0.0'
>>> dumps(np.complex(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0j is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.complex_(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0j is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.complex64(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0j is not JSON serializable
>>> dumps(np.complex128(0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 0j is not JSON serializable
```

So, no `complex` type is serializable, that makes sense.

But `bool` works and `bool_` doesn't. `int` works, but anything else with `int` in its name doesn't. `float`, `float_` and `float64` are all fine, but `float16` and `float32` are not.

*Why is this the case?* Obviously, they can all easily be converted to a string, the stacktrace even shows `repr()` being used to display their value. *Might this be unintentional? Or is there a good reason for this behaviour?*

Comment: Are you creating the `np.float32(...)` object directly?  Or is it extracted from an array?  Have tried serializing the `arr.tolist()` equivalent?

Comment: If you need to serialize an element of an array, consider using the `.item()` method to convert it to a Python scalar.

Comment: See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050108/convert-numpy-type-to-python `Convert numpy type to python`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data types that are JSON serializable are all Python built-ins:

```
>>> np.int is int
True
>>> np.float is float
True
>>> np.bool is bool
True
```

So all NumPy data types that you show are not JSON serializable. At least is consistent.

`np.float`_ is the same as `np.float64` (tested on MacOS):

```
>>> np.float_ is np.float64
True
```

The help says:

`np.float64`

> 64-bit floating-point number.  Character code 'd'. Python float
>   compatible.

Whereas:

`np.float32`

> 32-bit floating-point number.  Character code 'f'. C float compatible.

So, Python float compatible types work with `json.dumps()`, but C compatible ones don't.

Comment: Then why do `float64` and `float_` work? `>>> np.float64 is float` and `>>> np.float_ is float` both return `False`.

Comment: You can also look at the `__mro__`.  `np.float64.__mro__` includes `float`,  np.float32.__mro__` does not.