# Python Vamp Plugin JSON Encoder

Tags: python, json

I'm using in Python a [VAMP plugin](https://www.vamp-plugins.org/):

```
import vamp
import librosa
data, rate = librosa.load("example.mp3")
chroma = vamp.collect(data, rate, "nnls-chroma:nnls-chroma")
```

I have to decode results in a json object. Since the Vamp plugin uses a specific object `vampy.RealTime` object to wrap numbers I wrote an `Encoder` for that, otherwise you will get a `TypeError: (integer) is not JSON serializing` - see here for this specific error: ["TypeError: (Integer) is not JSON serializable" when serializing JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942364/typeerror-integer-is-not-json-serializable-when-serializing-json-in-python)

For this reason I wrote a custom JSON Encoder that uses the conversion to number from the `vampy.RealTime` object, taken from [here](https://github.com/c4dm/vampy-host/blob/master/test/test_realtime.py)

```
import json

class VampJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, vamp.vampyhost.RealTime):
            r = vamp.vampyhost.RealTime('seconds', obj)
             return r
        return super(VampJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

but when I run it like

```
json.dumps(chroma, sort_keys=True, indent=4, cls=VampJSONEncoder)
```

I get a

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```