# python: converting an numpy array data type from int64 to int

Tags: python, types

I am somewhat new to python and I am using python modules in another program (ABAQUS). The question, however, is completely python related.

In the program, I need to create an array of integers. This array will later be used as an input in a function defined in ABAQUS. The problem is to do with the data type of the integers. In the array, the integers have data type 'int64'. However, I am getting the following error when I input the array to the desired function:

> "Only INT, FLOAT and DOUBLE supported by the ABAQUS interface (use multiarray with typecode int if standard long is 64 bit)"

I do not need assistance with ABAQUS. If i convert the data type to 'int' in python, that would suffice. I thought that I could simply use the int() function to convert the data type. This did not work. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: `a.astype(int)`

Comment: @Sebastian: That still leaves the data type as int64. It does work for changing the data type from int to float. But not for int64 to int.

Comment: use any type you want e.g., `np.int32`

Comment: That works perfectly well, thank you! I was typing just ".astype(int)". I didn't realize "int" would give the platform dependent data type. Thanks again!

Comment: upvoted since it *seems* this answer solved the OP question

Comment: @Srikanth could you provide an answer to your question below and accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting numpy dtypes to native python types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types)

Comment: correct answer, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types is:
```
a.item()
```

Answer (score 36):

[numpy.ndarray.tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html#numpy.ndarray.tolist) will do it:

```
a.tolist()
```

If your data is a pandas series you can call their [tolist](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) wrapper with the same result.

Answer (score 25):

@J.F. Sebastian's answer:

```
a.astype(numpy.int32)
```

Comment: This will work when passing the array to a function. In case, you want to change the type of the array, you need to assign to the array: a = a.astype(...)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `item()` method for `numpy.int64` object, as [Mike T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11389998/2741416) in another similar question explained.

Official documentation is here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.item.html#numpy.chararray.item

Answer (score 0):

In the end, if you convert an list of int64 values to int with numpy, you will have a numpy value (int64, int32, etc). In case you want a regular int (not numpy int), I found a way which is working. You will convert it to string, and then convert to list! enjoy...

```
import ast

a = ast.literal_eval(str(a))
```

Answer (score -6):

If it's a pandas serise, you can first convert it to Dataframe, then use df.to_dict(), then the numpy.int64 will convert to int

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,size=(3,4)),
index=np.arange(3))

In [4]: type(df[0][0])

Out[4]: numpy.int64

In [5]: dict_of_df = df.to_dict()

In [6]: type(dict_of_df[0][0])

Out[6]: int
```