# Dumping large nested dictionary into JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

I have a large nested dictionary with strings, floats and integers as data. I want to dump it into a JSON string, but a direct dump gives me an error:

```
json_dictionary = json.dumps(mapped_dictionary)


TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable
```

So I tried to use this:

```
json_dictionary = json.dumps(str(mapped_dictionary))
```

This seemed to work at first but then I found out that the `str` function on the nested dictionary truncates the values after a certain point and then shows the rest of content. It's not dumping the entire nested dictionary, which is rather large.

I am wondering if there is a limit to the `str` function, and if so, what is a good workaround to have a nested dictionary with mixed type data to be dumped into a JSON object?

Comment: Ideally, you want to traverse the dictionary and convert each int64 to an int. Do not rely on `str()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error specified, JSON doesn't know how to serialize objects of type int64. Converting those objects to int should fix the issue. While I don't know the full scope of your problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648624/python-converting-an-numpy-array-data-type-from-int64-to-int) should help.