# pandas dataframe to excel with win32 : numpy datatype error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, win32com

I am trying to export a pandas dataframe to excel using win32.

The export seems to work only when the dataframe does not include numpy datatypes.

**How can I convert numpy datatypes to their COM variant ?**

Here a reproducible example :

```
 import pandas as pd
 from win32com.client import Dispatch

 # Prepare data

 # data without numpy data type
 xdata1 = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
     'year' : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2001],
     'pop'  : [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9 ]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(xdata1, columns = ['year', 'state', 'pop'])
xT1 = [tuple(x) for x in data1.values]# # data to tuples

# data with numpy type
data2 = pd.crosstab(data1.state, data1.year)
xT2 = [tuple(x) for x in data2.values]  # data to tuples

# export the data 
 from win32com.client import Dispatch
 xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
 xlApp.Visible = 1
 xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
 xlSheet = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

 # write to excel
  xlSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = 'Python Rules!'   # THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED

 # Write to a range : data without numpy data type
  FirstRow = 2
  FirstCol = 3
  LastRow = FirstRow + len(xT1) - 1 # Number of records
  LastCol =  FirstCol + len(xT1[0]) - 1        # Number of columns
   xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol), xlSheet.Cells(LastRow , LastCol)).Value = xT1  # THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED 



# Write to a range : data WITH  numpy data type
FirstRow = 2
FirstCol = 5
LastRow = FirstRow + len(xT2) - 1 # Number of records
LastCol =  FirstCol + len(xT2[0]) - 1        # Number of columns
xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol), xlSheet.Cells(LastRow , LastCol)).Value = xT2
```

THIS LINE PRODUCES AN ERROR

**TypeError: Objects of type 'numpy.int64' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT (but obtaining the buffer() of this object could)**

P.S: before someone asks (or suggest another way to export to export). I am using win32 on purpose because it is the only way I found to write to existing, pre-prepared excel file and keep the styles

P.P.S : 
Inspired by this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/), a solution I came up with is to change the type of each single element of the dataframe 
I am sure there are better ways

```
def fnConvertdType (xListofList):
     newListofList = []
     for itemList in xListofList:
         xList = []
         for item in itemList:
             xList.append(np.asscalar(np.int16(item)))
         newListofList.append(xList)
     return newListofList
```