# Convert numpy scalar to simple python type

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with a single value (scalar) which I would like to convert to correspoding Python data type. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(3)
b = np.array('3')
```

I could convert them to `int` and `str` by casting:

```
a_int = int(a)
b_str = str(b)
```

but I need to know the types in advance. I would like to convert `a` to an integer and `b` to a string without explicit type checking. Is there a simple way to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(3)
b = np.array('3')
a_int = a.tolist()
b_str = b.tolist()
print type(a_int), type(b_str)
```

should work

Answer (score 11):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11389998), use the [`obj.item()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method to get the Python scalar type:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(3).item()
b = np.array('3').item()
print(type(a))  # <class 'int'>
print(type(b))  # <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cast *ints* to *str*, and *str* to *int* without needing to know the type in advance. What it does is determine to call either **(str)** or **(int)** on (a/b). the inline 'a if b else c' is equivalent to the ?: ternary operator (which you may be familiar with).

```
a = '1'
a_res = (str if type(a) == type(1) else int)(a)
print(type(a_res))

b = 1
b_res = (str if type(b) == type(1) else int)(b)
print(type(b_res))
```

Produces:

```
>>> 
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

As you can see, the same code is used to convert both a and b.

Comment: Thanks. This becomes a bit cumbersome when you have more possible types like float, boolean, etc. That's why I prefer answer of Mr E