# Difference between Python float and numpy float32

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between the built in `float` and `numpy.float32`?

**Example**

```
a = 58682.7578125
print type(a)
print a
print type(numpy.float32(a))
print numpy.float32(a)
```

Output:

```
<type 'float'>
58682.7578125
<type 'numpy.float32'>
58682.8
```

I've found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) that `numpy.float32` is:

> float32   Single precision float: sign bit, 8 bits exponent, 23 bits
>   mantissa

didn't find what the built in `float` format is.

Comment: In your example `float_32 = np.float32(a);print(float_32 == a)` prints True - ??

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Python's standard `float` type is a C `double`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric

NumPy's standard `numpy.float` is the same, and is also the same as `numpy.float64`.

Comment: Note that `numpy.float` is just an alias to Python's `float` type. It is not a numpy scalar type like `numpy.float64`. The name is only exposed for backwards compatibility with a very early version of numpy that inappropriately exposed `numpy.float64` as `numpy.float`, causing problems when people did `from numpy import *`.

Comment: note that a = np.float32(1), b = np.float64(1), c = np.float(1) then type(a) is numpy.float32, type(b) is numpy.float64, type(c) is float and isinstance(a, float) is False, isinstance(b, float) is True and isinstance(c) is also True.

Comment: The page you link to currently says “Floating point numbers are **usually** implemented using double in C…” (emphasis added), not that Python’s `float` type **is** a C `double`. Did it say something different when you wrote this?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Very old versions of Python literally said "Floating point numbers are implemented using double in C."  Now they say "usually implemented using double in C," which I take to mean something like "Most people use a Python implementation written in C, and `double` is the type used there."  As for CPython, it always uses `double`, and the source code says "PyFloatObject represents a (double precision) floating point number."  Do you know of an implementation that uses something substantively different?

Comment: Im confused as to why this is accepted, the question is about numpy.float32

Comment: @9Guy: The question says what `numpy.float32` is, and asks to compare it with the builtin `float`.  So this answer explains what the built `float` is.

Answer (score 2):

Data type-wise numpy floats and built-in Python floats are the same, however boolean operations on numpy floats return `np.bool_` objects, which always return `False` for `val is True`. Example below:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: an_np_float = np.float32(0.3)
   ...: a_normal_float = 0.3
   ...: print(a_normal_float, an_np_float)
   ...: print(type(a_normal_float), type(an_np_float))

0.3 0.3
<class 'float'> <class 'numpy.float32'>
```

Numpy floats can arise from scalar output of array operations. If you weren't checking the data type, it is easy to confuse numpy floats for native floats.

```py
In [2]: criterion_fn = lambda x: x <= 0.5
   ...: criterion_fn(a_normal_float), criterion_fn(an_np_float)

Out[2]: (True, True)
```

Even boolean operations look correct. However the result of the numpy float isn't a native boolean datatype, and thus can't be truthy.

```py
In [3]: criterion_fn(a_normal_float) is True, criterion_fn(an_np_float) is True
Out[3]: (True, False)

In [4]: type(criterion_fn(a_normal_float)), type(criterion_fn(an_np_float))
Out[4]: (bool, numpy.bool_)
```

According to [this github thread](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5942), `criterion_fn(an_np_float) == True` will evaluate properly, but that goes against the PEP8 style guide.

Instead, extract the native float from the result of numpy operations. You can do `an_np_float.item()` to do it explicitly (ref: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types)) or simply pass values through `float()`.