# Pandas df.astype('float32') loses a lot of precision

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, precision

Why does a `float64` value `123456789.0` in a Pandas.DataFrame gets converted to `123456792.0`, preserving only 7 significant digits?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([123456789.0])

#              0
# 0  123456789.0

df = df.astype('float32')

#              0
# 0  123456792.0
```

Comment: Isn't it expected that you loss precision when converting to lower precision floating point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770993/float64-to-float32-conversion-gives-unexpected-result

Comment: It is just the rule

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, `float32` is `numpy`'s `dtype`. The reason why you see some difference in the precision when converting `float64` to `float32` is because `123456789.0` cannot be accurately represented using `float32` which is a 32-bit dtype (1 sign bit, 8 bits exponent, 23 bits mantissa).

In general, `float32` requires half of the memory  that `float64` requires to represent a numerical value , however `float32` can represent numbers less accurately compared to `float64`.

Note there is no workaround for this. If you need to represent particular numbers that cannot be represented using a 32-bit dtype like `float32`, then go for higher precision dtypes (`float64`).