# Wrong return using ctypeslib from numpy

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

These are the C files:

**addone.h**

```
#ifndef __ADDONE
#define __ADDONE
void  addone(float *in_data, int size);
#endif
```

**addone.c**

```
void addone(float *in_data, int size)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    in_data[i] = in_data[i] + 1;
  }
}
```

And I am trying to use this function with ctypes from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ctypeslib as npct
from ctypes import c_int

array_1d_float = npct.ndpointer(dtype=np.float, ndim=1, flags="CONTIGUOUS")
libcd = npct.load_library("libaddone", ".")
libcd.addone.restype = None
libcd.addone.argtypes = [array_1d_float, c_int]

def addone(in_array):
    return libcd.addone(in_array, len(in_array))

def main():
    out = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float)
    print out
    addone(out)
    print out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when I run this file I obtain wrong results:

```
python test.py
[1. 2. 3.]
[24.00000378   2.00000047   3.     ]
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by using:

```
void addone(double *in_data, int size)
```

Instead of:

```
void addone(float *in_data, int size)
```

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16964006, `np.float` is an alias for [python](/questions/tagged/python)'s built-in `float` type, which corresponds to a `double` in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Before replacing `float` with `double`:

```
$ python test.py
[ 1.  2.  3.]
[ 24.00000378   2.00000047   3.        ]
```

After replacing `float` with `double` and recompiling the library:

```
$ python test.py
[ 1.  2.  3.]
[ 2.  3.  4.]
```

Alternatively, you could leave your [c](/questions/tagged/c) code unchanged and use `np.float32` instead of `np.float` in your [python](/questions/tagged/python) code.