# Strange behavior when casting numpy.float64 to float

Tags: python, numpy, casting, floating-point, sympy

I'm having the strangest behavior with an object generated by `numpy.arange`:

```
for i in numpy.arange(xo, xn+h, h):
    xs.append(float(i))
```

In this case, `xo=1`, `xn=4`, `h=0.1`.

Now, I expected `xs[-1]` to be exactly equal to `4.0` == `float(4)`. However, I get the following:

```
>>> foo = xs[-1]
>>> foo == float(4)
False
>>> float(foo) == float(4)
False
>>> foo
4.0
>>> type(foo)
<type 'float'>
>>> int(sympy.ceiling(4.0)), int(sympy.ceiling(foo))
4 5
```

What on earth is happening here?

Placing `print type(i)` in the `for` loop prints `<type 'numpy.float64'>`. Perhaps something going on during the `float(i)` casting? Using [`numpy.asscalar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11389998/2032568) doesn't change anything.

Using `math.ceil(foo)` instead of `sympy.ceiling(foo)` issues the same thing (that's the part I actually need to work).

Comment: numpy.float64 vs sympy.float? if you use sympy, you may run into problems like that i guess?

Comment: @usethedeathstar I used the built-in `float()` for casting. Sympy was only used on the last line of the console I/O above. And, as I said, using `math.ceil` instead of `sympy.ceiling` returns the same.

Comment: You should avoid `np.arange` with floating point numbers. Rather use `np.linspace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [10]: for i in numpy.arange(xo, xn+h, h):
        xs.append(float(i))
....:     

In [11]: xs
Out[11]: 
[1.0,
1.1,
1.2000000000000002,
1.3000000000000003,
1.4000000000000004,
1.5000000000000004,
1.6000000000000005,
1.7000000000000006,
1.8000000000000007,
1.9000000000000008,
2.000000000000001,
2.100000000000001,
2.200000000000001,
2.300000000000001,
2.4000000000000012,
2.5000000000000013,
2.6000000000000014,
2.7000000000000015,
2.8000000000000016,
2.9000000000000017,
3.0000000000000018,
3.100000000000002,
3.200000000000002,
3.300000000000002,
3.400000000000002,
3.500000000000002,
3.6000000000000023,
3.7000000000000024,
3.8000000000000025,
3.9000000000000026,
4.000000000000003]
```

This is why you do not get the wanted result, due to floating point accuracy, it cant give True to your test. This also explains why if you do a round-operation like ceiling on it, that you get five instead of four.

edit:
to check if x and y are the same (within some margin of error), you could do the following, but i think there is (should be) something already in python that can do this for you

```
def isnear(x,y, precision = 1e-5):
    return abs(x-y)<precision
```

edit2:
or as ali_m said:

```
numpy.allclose(x, y, atol = 1e-5)
```

Comment: Well, it strikes me as odd that after casting with `float(xs[-1])` you get just `4.0` as the output. What would the best approach be to get it right, then? `round(i)`?

Comment: @Alex i think there is something implemented in python to check if x is near to y, if you would implement it yourself, you could try  abs(x-y)<something

Comment: @Alex: Instead of testing `f1 == f2`, where `f1` and `f2` are both floating point numbers, it is usually best to test `abs(f1-f2) < eps`, where `eps` is an appropriately small-sized number. In this case, a value of `eps` anywhere between 0.01 and 0.0000000000001 would be fine.

Comment: @Alex Does this answer your question, or do you need more info on it?

Comment: For convenience you could also use [`np.allclose(x, y, atol=eps)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)

Comment: @ali_m Yeah, thanks.  I knew it was already somewhere in python or numpy, (just didn't know where). I edited it in, so people see it in my post directly, instead of needing to look at the comments on this post as well (just so it is more clear).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really strange - it is just the way that floating point arithmetic works because it cannot represent most values exactly. If you do repeated computations in floating point (`arange()` here is adding 0.1 to 1 and then adding 0.1 to that sum another 29 times) and if the numbers you are dealing with are not exactly representable in floating point, you won't get an exact answer at the end of the computation. The best article to read on this is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).