# How to check if a value is of a NumPy type?

Tags: python, numpy

Imagine you have a value that might or might not be one of the NumPy dtypes. How would you write a function that checks which is the case?

```
def is_numpy(value):
    # how to code?
```

Comment: I believe `isinstance(value, numpy.ndarray)`, should work as all(I think) `numpy` data structures are subclasses of `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Do you want to detect just scalars (e.g., instances of `float64`, `uint32`, etc.), or both scalars and ndarray instances?  (Or something else?)

Comment: I intended to ask about scalar values only, not `ndarray`s

Comment: In that case, `isinstance(value, np.generic)` might be an option.

Answer (score 2):

One way I've found that works was used by Mike T in his answer to [Converting numpy dtypes to native python types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types):

```
def is_numpy(value):
    return hasattr(value, 'dtype')
```

I'm not sure whether or not this is the preferred method, but it's relatively simple and clean.