# Multiplying the values in two columns: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to multiply the values in two separate columns

The type of the elements in the first column is `'numpy.float64'`

That of the second column is `'float'`

When I do

```
new_column = df['first_column'] * df['second column']
```

I get

> 'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

I don't really understand why I cannot multiply the values of `numpy.float64` and `float`. Aren't they similar to each other and multipliable?

Comment: This question explains how to convert numpy types to native python types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types

Comment: You're not trying to multiply the values of `numpy.float64` and `float`, that's the problem. I'm guessing the first set of values is a `list` and not a numpy array?

Comment: Mark. The types of both first and second set of values are 'pandas.core.series.Series.'

Comment: You could certainly use `zip` to go through both series with a list comprehension and multiply each element individually. I'm not familiar with pandas so I don't know if there are other options.

Comment: can you provide a sample dataframe which reproduces error.

Comment: We need more information about the `df`.  Isn't there some sort of `info` or `dtypes` command in `pandas`?  There's something about the 2 `df` columns that doesn't match your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your error message with:

```
In [267]: [1,2,3]*3.43
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-267-fc9c3bc4b243> in <module>()
----> 1 [1,2,3]*3.43

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

In Python (not numpy or pandas), a list or other sequence times an integer replicates the sequence:

```
In [268]: [1,2,3]*3
Out[268]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

If

```
df['first_column'] * df['second column']
```

is producing the error, then one term is a sequence (e.g. list) the other a float.  Another possibility is that one is a object dtype array, and contains one or more lists.

```
In [271]: np.array([(2,3),(3,)])*3
Out[271]: array([(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3)], dtype=object)
In [272]: np.array([(2,3),(3,)])*3.34
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-272-c3152ad55f88> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([(2,3),(3,)])*3.34

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

It could even be a mix of floats and lists, doing number * on the numbers and replication on the lists.

```
In [283]: np.array([(2,3),(3,),12])*np.array([[3],[2]])
Out[283]: 
array([[(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3), 36],
       [(2, 3, 2, 3), (3, 3), 24]], dtype=object)
```

More likely it's an object array (or data series) with a mix of numbers and strings:

```
In [287]: np.array(['astring',12],dtype=object)*np.array([[3]])
Out[287]: array([['astringastringastring', 36]], dtype=object)
In [288]: np.array(['astring',12],dtype=object)*np.array([[3.23]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-288-5a02408d1a73> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(['astring',12],dtype=object)*np.array([[3.23]])

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try unsafe casting like so:

```
numpy.multiply(A, B, out=A, casting='unsafe')
```

Comment: I tried, but I get the same error:TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: `casting` doesn't get around the Python sequence error that I identified.