# Pandas to_dict type conversion is context specific

Tags: pandas

I am finding that the output of the pandas dataframe classes to_dict method is different for columns of the same dtype in different dataframes.  I have one dataframe where all columns are of type int64.  to_dict on this dataframe will print values of type int64.  In another dataframe where there is a column of type int64 and another column of a different type, the int64 column values, after to_dict, are represented as type int.  Is there an explanation why this method should be producing a representation of a value that is dependent on types of other values w/in the same dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 'str'}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}])

l1 = df1.to_dict(orient='records')
l2 = df2.to_dict(orient='records')

for i in l1:
    for k in i:
        print(type(i[k]))


for i in l2:
    for k in i:
        print(type(i[k]))
```

output:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Ideally, I would like some consistency.  Whatever that may be.  Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting numpy dtypes to native python types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types)

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types

Comment: A workaround would be to cast the DataFrame as object first: `df2.astype(object).to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Gagne & ayhan!  I'll definitely apply one of these solutions.  I'm mainly curious why to_dict behaves differently in these two separate contexts.

Comment: It seems like a bug to me. Raise an issue on github maybe?

Comment: @ayhan, as always, looks like i'm a bit late: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22620