# Scikit's LabelEncoder uses `numpy.int64` instead of integers in `inverse_transform`

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

If you `fit` an `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` with labels of type `int`, for some reason during `inverse_transform` it returns `numpy.int64` type labels.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labels = [2,4,6] # just a list of `int`s
e = LabelEncoder().fit(labels)
encoded = e.transform([4,6,2])
decoded = e.inverse_transform(encoded)
type(decoded[0])
# returns  <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So I guess I have 2 questions

1. Why would it do that?
2. How can someone avoid that without custom code?

(I fell on this problem when Flask's `jsonify` could not marshal `np.int64` to JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would it do that?

Because `transform` and `inverse_transform` return numpy arrays and

> [An item extracted from an array, e.g., by indexing, will be a Python object whose type is the scalar type associated with the data type of the array.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

In this case the scalar type is `int64`.

> How can someone avoid that without custom code?

If you need to get a single element, use `decoded.item(0)`. If you need the entire array, use `decoded.tolist()`. See [Converting numpy dtypes to native python types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types) for more.

Comment: I just realized I never took the time to thank you for this concise and informative answer. Thanks